# Error in installing perl extension on postgres-9.4 in Ubuntu

Tags: perl, postgresql, ubuntu

I have installed postgresql 9.4 on Ubuntu 15.10.On installing 
postgresql-plperl-9.4 via apt it shows error.

```
sudo apt-get install -f postgresql-plperl-9.4
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 postgresql-plperl-9.4 : Depends: libperl5.14 (>= 5.14.2) but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I have installed libperl-dev and libperl with version 5.20.2 but It doesn't solve the problem.

```
$dpkg -l | grep libperl
ii  libperl-dev                                   5.20.2-6                                   amd64        Perl library: development files
ii  libperl5.20                                   5.20.2-6                                   amd64        shared Perl library
ii  libperlio-gzip-perl                           0.18-3build1                               amd64        module providing a PerlIO layer to gzip/gunzip
```

Also perl is installed of the same version

```
$perl -v

This is perl 5, version 20, subversion 2 (v5.20.2) built for x86_64-linux-gnu-thread-multi
(with 51 registered patches, see perl -V for more detail)
```

Comment: Please go to the following [link](http://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies-after-adding-a-ppa) and let me know if that helped you

Comment: Thanks for reply. I already tried that also I don't have broken dependencies.
{code}
$sudo apt-get install postgresql-plperl-9.4
Reading package lists... Done
.......
....
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 postgresql-plperl-9.4 : Depends: libperl5.14 (>= 5.14.2) but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

          sudo apt-get install -f 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PL/Perl embeds a Perl interpreter into the PostgreSQL server. The PL/Perl package you are trying to install expects the system Perl to be Perl 5.14, but it's Perl 5.20. It can't be installed.

I suspect that your repository list is messed up because the `postgresql-plperl-9.4` [package](http://packages.ubuntu.com/wily/postgresql-plperl-9.4) for Ubuntu 15.10 correctly links to Perl 5.20, not Perl 5.14.

Fix your package manager.

Comment: My understanding was that  libperl5.14 (>= 5.14.2)  ==> libperl5.20  should work as version 5.20 > 5.14.2.

Comment: While maintenance releases of Perl maintain binary backwards compatibility, this is not maintained between versions of Perl. That means that something linked against 5.14.0 can run with 5.14.2, but not with 5.20.2. It would need to be recompiled. /// Anyway, you're heading in the wrong direction. You wouldn't want to install your package even if you could. Install the `postgresql-plperl-9.4` for Ubuntu 15.10 instead of the one you are trying to install.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I was not aware of perl version compatibility thing. I am already installing postgresql-plperl-9.4 for Ubuntu 15.10 as I am doing it via apt. I more thing would help me increase my knowledge as apt is denying to install  libperl5.14 (>= 5.14.2). How does it come to know about compatibility of perl as it can differ from lib to lib.

Comment: No, you're not. Again, the [postgresql-plperl-9.4 for Ubuntu 15.10](http://packages.ubuntu.com/wily/postgresql-plperl-9.4) doesn't have a dependency on libperl5.14. Fix your repository list and/or update your cache.

Answer (score 0):

Since, I couldn't be able to add comment I am adding up comment as answer,
Once you please install the package manually of same version and then you see if the same problem exists actually the same problem I faced for different package and now it is working fine So please add it manually and let me know
Thanks

Comment: Can it result in broken dependency as by default perl v5.4.20 is installled on Ubuntu 15.10 and I will install libperl-dev==5.14.2 which should not be compatible.